# MongoDB: Get index of element within collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a collection of documents of the format:

```json
{
  "user": { "username": "string" }
  "score": 123
}
```

I want to find a user's rank within the collection.

```js
collection.aggregate([
    { $sort: { score: -1 } }, // sort by score descending
    { 
        $project: {
            score: '$score'
            rank: {
                $indexOfArray: [ 
                    '$', // I don't know what to place here
                    { 'user.username': 'myUser' }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

How do I treat the collection as an array?

I'm looking for this result:

```json
[
  {
    "score": 123,
    "rank": 1
  }
]
```

Comment: What's the json you are expecting as a result?

Comment: @Caconde updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can achieve this by performing a self lookup. The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match:{
            "user.username":"B"
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup:{
            "from":"my_collection_name",
            "let":{
                "score":"$score"
            },
            "pipeline":[
                {
                    $match:{
                        $expr:{
                            $gt:["$score","$$score"]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $group:{
                        "_id":null,
                        "above":{
                            $sum:1
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "as":"selfLookup"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind:{
            "path":"$selfLookup",
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays":true
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "_id":0,
            "score":1,
            "rank":{
                $cond:[
                    {
                        $eq:["$selfLookup.above",null]
                    },
                    1,
                    {
                        $sum:["$selfLookup.above",1]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d657d2d7d0ab652c42315f3"),
    "user" : {
        "username" : "A"
    },
    "score" : 123
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d657d2d7d0ab652c42315f4"),
    "user" : {
        "username" : "B"
    },
    "score" : 122
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d657d2d7d0ab652c42315f5"),
    "user" : {
        "username" : "C"
    },
    "score" : 121
}
```

**Output:**

```
{ "score" : 122, "rank" : 2 }
```

**Explanation:** We are calculating the count of users which has scores more than the score of the searched user('B' in this case). If no records are found, rank is 1, else the rank would be count + 1.

Comment: When I run this, the first aggregation stage (match) reduces the collection to 1 item, so every rank is 1.

Comment: No. The first aggregation stage gets us the record which has the searched user name. From that record, we also get a score. That score is then used to lookup in the same collection (2nd aggregation stage).

Comment: I see.  I'm still getting rank 1 no matter which username I type in.  When I add `foo: '$selfLookup.above'` to my `$project`, it doesn't appear to exist.

Comment: Can you please add some sample data?

Comment: You are changing the collection name in lookup right? in ```from``` field?

Comment: Ahh!  That was the issue.  Thanks!